# How to change Android Wear's settings via adb

Tags: wear-os, adb

Recently, I'm searching how to change the Android Wear's settings
and some of them are found in settings.db.

1. Brightness

   ```
   adb shell settings put system screen_brightness_mode 0
   adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 0
   ```
2. Airplane mode

   ```
   adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
   ```
3. Theater mode

   ```
   adb shell settings put global theater_mode_on 0
   ```
4. Wi-Fi

   ```
   adb shell settings put global wifi_on 0 & adb reboot
   ```

However, I cannot find the following settings in settings.db

1. Always-on screen
2. Wrist gesture

Please tell me if you know them!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For always-on screen I use: `adb shell svc power stayon true`
Don't know about the Wrist gesture, all I could find was wake_gesture_enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
However, I cannot change the always-on screen setting by "adb shell svc power stayon true".